# What's the most efficient way to export files from EC2 to S3 on timed intervals?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, architecture

Working on a problem at the moment where I want to export a file on an EC2 instance running a Windows AMI at four hour intervals to an S3 bucket.  Currently, the architecture I'm thinking is as follows.

```
1. CloudWatch Events rule using scheduled trigger
2. Rule triggers Lambda function to run
3. Lambda function would use some form of the AWS CLI on the windows EC2 instance to extract (sync, cp, etc.) the file
4. File is placed is S3 bucket
```

Does anyone see a path that's more efficient than this one?  I want to ensure that I'm handling this in the most straightforward manner.  Thanks in advance for any input!

Comment: Why not just use the Windows task scheduler to run a .bat script that calls an `aws s3 cp` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite difficult to have external code (eg an AWS Lambda function) cause something to execute on a Windows computer. You could use Systems Manager Run Command, but that's a rather complex solution.

It would be much simpler to have the Windows computer **push** the files to Amazon S3:

- Create a scheduled task in Windows
- Use `aws s3 cp` or `aws s3 sync` to copy the files to Amazon S3

Done!

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I ended up doing and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Your solution seems solid.  Alternatively you may want to write daemon-like service (background process) that runs on each EC2 and does the data transfer from that instance to S3.  What I like about your solution is how you can centrally control the scheduling easily.  For my distributed solution you can have the processes read from central config, but that seems more complicated than the CW/Lambda solution.

For the EC2 process solution, this may be useful:
[How to mount Amazon S3 Bucket as a Windows Drive](https://tntdrive.com/mount-amazon-s3-bucket.aspx), but it should be easy (and more scalable) to just use the AWS SDK instead to talk to S3